# The command "ytplayer.config.args.url_encoded_fmt_maps.split(",")" isn't showing the video URLs in the developer tools console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I'm trying to get the URLs of a YouTube video by typing the command `ytplayer.config.args.url_encoded_fmt_stream_map` or `ytplayer.config.args.url_encoded_fmt_stream_map.split(",")` on the developer tools console but neither of those seem to work. The console just displays the message "undefined" when I enter the first one and when I enter the command with `.split(",")` at the end, it displays the following error message:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'split')
>         at <anonymous>:1:42
```

Comment: Youtube stopped exposing this object. I don't see any alternative.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know. Then how would you recommend I proceed? I'm taking an online course and the project I´m doing is a YouTube video downloader and for that I need the links. The course videos are a quite outdated and it often causes problems.